# Ruby On Rails: How to use find with the has_one relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models A and B where:

A has_one B

I therefore have added a foreign key to A that associates every instance of A with the id of an instance of B. Note that I do know want this to be a 1-1 relationship.

How can I use A.find() to get all the instances of A that are associated with an instance of B with a certain attribute from B (B.name for example)?

I know that this can be done with a SQL join between the two tables but is there an elegant way of doing this in ROR?

Comment: Your foreign_key must be in B and not A : [Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the right associations setup:

```
time_range = (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight
Client.joins(:orders).where(:orders => {:created_at => time_range})
```

This is from the [Active Record Querying guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Answer (score 0):

`has_one` association requires foreign key in belonging model.
Please take a look on RailsGuides - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association

Comment: If I don't care about the has_one relationship and remove it, how can I actually stil get the result I want?